# Using eval() to refer to widgets in PYQT

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, eval

I have a series of spinboxes on a form I designed with Qt Designer names rate_0 to rate_6.  I would like to refer to one of these spinboxes based on the day of the week of a given date.

If a given spinbox's value can be referred to as self.ui.rate_0.value(), I know that I can use

```
eval("self.ui.rate_" + "0" + ".value()")
```

but somehow this does not seem to be the best Qt way or Pythonic way to do this.  It also seems that I can traverse the children of layouts but this also seems messy.

What is the best way to refer to widgets in a variable form?  More code below:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time
from rate_bulk_edit import *

class Bulk_rates(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_update_rates()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pb_update_rates.clicked.connect(self.update_rates)

    def update_rates(self):
        self.start_date = self.ui.start_date.date().toPyDate()
        self.end_date = self.ui.end_date.date().toPyDate()

        d = self.start_date - timedelta(days=1)
        delta = timedelta(days=1)
        while d <= self.end_date - timedelta(days=1):
            d += delta        
            QMessageBox.information(self, 
                                    "Test", 
                                    d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + " " + 
                                    str(eval("self.ui.rate_" + str(d.weekday()) + ".value()")))

        QMessageBox.information(self, "Rates...", "Rates updated!")


if __name__=="__main__":
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = Bulk_rates()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QWidgets should in the end be stored as any other Python attribute, so I think that what you are looking for is the built-in function [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr). In your code, the full string would look something like this in one line:

```
d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + " " + str(getattr(self.ui, 'rate ' + str(d.weekday())).value())
```

If you also want to check actively that the spinbox actually exists, it would look something like this:

```
spinbox = getattr(self.ui, 'rate_' + str(d.weekday()), None)
if spinbox is None:
     # Raise error or whatever
else:
     # Launch message box here
```